# Cannot SEND XTZ from Galleon

Tags: mytezosbaker

I deposited XTZ to my Galleon wallet.  But now I want to SEND them to another wallet address but it shows -0- balance.  How can I see, and send, my XTZ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to tezos stack exchange! how do you know the deposit was successful in the first place ? have you tried contacting cryptonomics ? what error message do you see if any ? your question contains too few details for people to assist you, try to give more infos!